# Enabling specific ciphersuites in openssl

Tags: kernel, openssl

I want to enable only these twelve cipher suites:

- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)

Apart from these, I wanted to disable all and to make it configurable.
Actually I am integrating the openssl 1.0.2 version source code with my application. Is there a way to configure without editing .c and .h files from the openssl source code?

Answer (score 0):

You should do what e.g. Apache does, and provide facilities for a configurable cipher string. You might want to check how Apache implemented the [SSLCipherSuite option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite), and the source code of [`openssl ciphers` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) might be useful too.